# at the ...of or in the ...of?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I know the "in the end of time" is wrong and "at the end of time" is right. But I do not know if we always use *"at the <sub>**________**</sub> of..."* or *"in the <sub>**________**</sub> of..."* .

For example, is "in the situation of primary scheduling" right, or "at the situation of primary scheduling"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, no, no, no. We don't "always" do much of anything when it comes to prepositions. It depends on the surrounding words.

For example:

> **In the situation of primary scheduling**, you need to know your available resources. (otherwise, your schedule may not be accurate)
>
> **At the time of primary scheduling**, we had more resources available. (now, some people have been laid off, and we need to develop a new schedule)

Both of those are fine, although I'd probably reword the first:

> **During primary scheduling,** you need to know your available resources.

I recommend looking up those pesky little English words we call *prepositions* – like *of, in, to, for* and *at* – in a good dictionary, such as [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in) or [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/of). Study the dozen or so definitions you'll find for each one, and notice how vague some of those definitions are (like, "concerning or showing someone or something"). You should come to two conclusions:

- No one is going to be able to briefly and concisely explain when to use *in* and when to use *at*.
- There may be some instances where either one could be used, because the possible meanings of the two words overlap.

Comment: _In the situation_... you're talking about something concerning the act or event of "primary scheduling". Note that this is different than _in the **event** of loss of cabin pressure_..., where it means _if we lose cabin pressure,_... _At the time of_... is something ("primary scheduling") happened in the past, and we are talking about that [past] time.

Comment: @Phil - Only because, in my example, the words that follow point to the past. That same introductory phrase, word-for-word, could just as easily allude to some event in the future, too: _"At the time of primary scheduling, all our donations had better be in, and everyone should have already completed their training."_ P.S. I like your cabin pressure example - good one!